# Manipulate 'Most Visited' and 'Recently Closed' on OSX via Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a security extension that allows someone to completely wipe history et al. Works great except I can't seem to get rid of 'Most Visited' and 'Recently Closed' in the Mac OS X menu bar! I can't see a direct way in the api to manipulate those, either. It looks like I can get those menu items by query, but not clear them.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot get rid of those from history. It has been like that since the beginning. Your best bet is to submit an issue for that.

http://crbug.com/new

By the way, I recall someone wanted the direct opposite, he wanted to clear his history but maintain the Recently Closed list so that he can reopen the last closed tab. :)